# asp.net how to close a dialoge box using intrapage linking in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I made a dialog box showing wrong password or username error but this doesn't close.
how to close this dialog box without refreshing the page,Code is like

```
            <asp:Panel ID="errorMsg" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <asp:Label ID="msg" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="errorHead" Text="Something is really Wrong :" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    <asp:button ID="try" OnClick="try_Click" runat="server" Text="Try Again" />

            </asp:Panel>
```

Code Behind :

```
    protected void try_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        errorMsg.Visible = false;
    }
```

errorMsg.visible is set to true when wrong input is made but after making it again false it doesn't close.

Answer (score 0):

The *OnClick* event will fire a PostBack refreshing the page.

You could try using javascript:

```
<script text="text/javascript">
   function hide(id){
     if(id)
       document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
   }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="try" OnClientClick='hide("<%=errorMsg.ClientId%>")'
     runat="server" Text="Try Again" />
```

Or you could simply wrap the dialogbox with an [Update Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The Update Panel allows you only to refresh a part of your website.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="errorMsg" runat="server" Visible="false">
      ...
      <asp:Button ID="try" OnClick="try_Click" 
           runat="server" Text="Try Again" />
    </asp:Panel>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```